# login in Yii opens new window insted of staying in same window

Tags: php, yii

I'm new in Yii framework, I build a system and there is a login page, when I make login it opens a new page instead of staying in the same page, how can i fix this problem

$this->redirect('mysite.com/site/home');

Login Form in view

```
<div class="login_form">
         <h3>Admin Login</h3>
         <form action="" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><label for="username">Username:</label></dt>
                        <dd><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="30" /></dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><label for="password">Password:</label></dt>
                        <dd><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" /></dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><label></label></dt>
                    </dl>
                     <dl class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
                     </dl>
                </fieldset>
         </form>
         </div>
```

in SiteController

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $form=new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
        {
            $form->attributes = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password']);
            if( $form->validate()  && $form->login() ) {
                Yii::app()->request->cookies['name'] = new CHttpCookie('mycookie', 'value');
                $this->redirect('mysite/site/home');
            }
            else {
                die('Invalid login');
            }
        }
        $this->render('login', array('form' => $form));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give any more info? show your view, or controller code or anything? with the info provided nobody can guess the reaon

Comment: sorry 4 that, i added the Sitecontroller and the view

Comment: still hard to guess.. does it open in a new wintdow after the login? after you submit the login form? I suppose there can be a problem in the redirect, you should try it this way: `$this->redirect('site/home')`

Comment: yes exactly after submit the login form it opens the homepage in a new window.
I tried $this->redirect('site/home') , same thing happened!

Comment: I solved it, in login form tag I added target="_top"
<form action="" method="post" target="_top">

Comment: So you could delete this question because of a non problem? Or is this just a workaround and your main problem still occurs?